# M-x man: How to open the buffer in the current window, and in `evil-normal-state'

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

When I type `M-x man`, it opens up a split and it behaves like a special buffer.

I want that when I invoke `M-x man` that it takes over the current window, and not open up any new splits. Also, I want it to behave like any normal evil text buffer beggining at evil-normal-state.

Is there a way to achieve that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing "normal" about `evil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet worked for me:

```
(with-eval-after-load "man" 
  (progn
    (evil-set-initial-state 'Man-mode 'normal)
    (setq Man-notify-method 'pushy)
  )
)
```

Comment: n.b. Unlike `eval-after-load` there's no need for the `progn` when you use `with-eval-after-load`.

Comment: Yes. The `&rest BODY` argument tells you that any number of forms may be supplied -- in contrast with the singular `FORM` argument required for `eval-after-load`.